# loop and setTimeout function still not working after some research

Tags: javascript

I did some research about loops and `setTimeout` function, but still its not working as I wish...

It opens all the links in same time **without** delay of 5 seconds per link that opened.

I would like it to open every link with 5 second delay after every each of them.

Code:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[class="mn-person-info__link ember-view"][id^="ember"]')
for (var i = 1; i <= links.length; i++) {
    (function(index) {
        setTimeout(function() { 
            window.open(links[index].href,'_blank'); 
        }, 5000);
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: make the `settimeout` go outside of the for-loop

Comment: Something like this?                                               
 function doSetTimeout(i) {
  setTimeout(function() { alert(i); }, 100);
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 2; ++i)
  doSetTimeout(i);

Comment: *"it open all the links in same time without delay of 5 seconds"* do you mean they all open immediately? Or it waits 5 seconds and then they all open at the same time? (I suspect the later, that's what I'd expect the code to do)

Comment: @MaorBahar I can't understand the question clearly, you are giving 5000ms for all timeouts, can you explain what you want to do clearly

Comment: I would like it to open every link with 5 second delay after every each of them

Answer (score 4):

Using a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) chain and [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), you can do this:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[class="mn-person-info__link ember-view"][id^="ember"]');

Array.from(links).reduce((chain, { href }) => {
  return chain.then(() => new Promise(resolve => {
    window.open(href, '_blank');
    setTimeout(resolve, 5000);
  }));
}, Promise.resolve())
```

If you don't want to do something quite this fancy and you're fine setting all your timeouts at once, you can simplify your `for` loop using [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Cleaner_code_in_inner_functions) instead of `var` and an [**IIFE**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[class="mn-person-info__link ember-view"][id^="ember"]');

for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() { 
    window.open(links[i].href, '_blank'); 
  }, 5000 * i);
}
```

Or even simpler, using [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring):

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[class="mn-person-info__link ember-view"][id^="ember"]');
var i = 0;

for (const { href } of links) {
  setTimeout(function() { 
    window.open(href, '_blank'); 
  }, 5000 * i++);
}
```

Comment: Thanks i'll try +1!

Comment: Where does `i` come from in the last example? In the second example, when the timeout callbacks are called `i` is always equals to `links.length - 1` since it's not "conserved" in its own scope. In the first example the first link is shown immediately, not with 5 sec timeout as expected from the question. Temporarily downvoted.

Comment: @try-catch-finally last one was a typo. Second to last is correct. It's called "lexical scoping". See the link I provided for [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Cleaner_code_in_inner_functions) in my answer. Last example is fixed. Please remove "temporary downvote".

Comment: Oh and to clarify, I don't think the asker actually wanted delay for the first link. It makes more sense to have some sort of immediate response to a user action than to initially wait 5 seconds, so that part was intentional.

Answer (score 2):

That's because all your timeouts are set immediately, almost at one time. So the ends of timeouts are take place almost on the same time. Try this:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[class="mn-person-info__link ember-view"][id^="ember"]')

for (var i = 1; i <= links.length; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      window .open(links[index].href,'_blank');
    }, 5000 * i);
  })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` is asyncronous. I would solve this specified problem with:

```
Array.from(links).reduce((a,e)=>{
    setTimeout(function() { window .open(e.href,'_blank');}, a);
    return a + 5000;
} ,5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

From the code above i assume that you wish to open the links once every 5 seconds so here are the improvements and suggestion made upon your code

```
// use JS hoisting for variable declarations
var 
    // Timer to store the next timer function reference
    timer,

    // The delay between each function call
    delay = 5000,

    // Set the desired selector 
    selectors = 'a[class="mn-person-info__link ember-view"][id^="ember"]',

    // Get the list of the required selectors.
    links = document.querySelectorAll(selectors);

// Create a function which will be called every X seconds
function openLink( index ){
    
    // validate that the index is not out of bound
    if (index === links.length){ 
        return;    
        }
    
    // get the current link and open new window with the link url
    window.open(links[index].href,'_blank'); 
 
    // Set the next timer to open the next window
    timer = setTimeout( openLink, delay, ++index);  
}

// Call the function for the first time with index = 0
openLink( 0 );
```

---

#### What does this code do?

The first section is declaration of the variables which will be used in this script. The preferred way to declare variables id to to use [hoisting](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/notes/note-4-two-words-about-hoisting/)

#### `Hoisting`

> Hoisting is a JavaScript mechanism where variables and function declarations are moved to the top of their scope before code execution.

#### `Timers`

If you wish to open the links in a sequence you should put them inside a function which will call them one after the other instead of using the `for loop`. The `for loop` will place all of them in the `call stack/event loop` and all of them will be executed after 5000 milliseconds since this is what set time out will so, it will schedule the execution of the code to 5000 milliseconds from now for all of them.

Im recommending you to watch the amazing lecture by **Philip Roberts**
[Philip Roberts: What the heck is the event loop anyway](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)

Saving the return value from the setTimeout will allow you to later on cancel the timer if you wish using the `clearTimeout( timer )`

#### Summary

Since you had a for loop it will simply loop over all your links. The `setTimeout` will set the scheduled execution time 5 seconds from now for all the links.
The **trick** here is to set the next timer after the current one is opened. This is why the sertTimeout is defined within the function itself.

The `setTimeout` gets a third param which is the parameter passed to the function when its being called.

Comment: you are right. i should fix it and check validation

Answer (score -2):

Easy way:

```
links.forEach(function(i, link) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        window.open(link.href,'_blank'); 
    }, 5000 * i);
});
```

Just wait *i * 5* seconds, where *i* is the index of the link

Comment: inside the `setTimeout` anonymous callback, `i - 1` will always be equal to `links.length - 1`, so it will open the last link every 5 seconds in a new window for every anchor tag in the `HTMLElementCollection`

Comment: I see. I just fixed it. Thank you for pointing out the issue.